# How to make CAS redirect to another protocol than http or https

Tags: cas

I try out a way make SSO work for my desktop application. For that to achieve I need CAS to redirect to a user defined protocol.

What I want to do:

call `https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-4.0.0/login?service=sso://myapplication`
and after successful login be redirected to `sso://myapplication?ticket=someTicket`

But what happens is, that I'm redirected to `https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-4.0.0/sso://myapplication?someTicket`.

Do I have to change something in configuration of CAS or is that a bug?

EDIT:

I'm using CAS out of the box, until now no configuration is done. The only thing I changed is to add `sso` as allowed protocol to `org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService` by `p:serviceId="^(https?|imaps?|sso?|file?)://.*"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it comes from the CAS server itself. The redirection to the service is managed by the login webflow: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/webflow/login/login-webflow.xml#L147.
I fear that this behaviour comes from the browser when a redirection is requested to an url which doesn't seem to be a valid one (I mean starting by http/https). I would try using a POST redirection using the method=POST parameter at login.